# javascript export * gives index.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript

I have a JS project and trying to use Redux. I created index.js file, but I'm getting an error index.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import userDataReducer from './userData/reducers';

//export { updateSelectedSections } from './userData/actions';
export * from './userData/actions';

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  userData: userDataReducer,
});
```

If I use that comment line everything works. What's more interesting I copied the same code from my previous Typescript project where it works. I assume it has something to do with JS?

Comment: Are you sure that inside `./userData/actions` you dont have a typo `exports` instead of `export`?

Comment: Is it compiling targeting Node.js/CommonJS and not used in that environment?

Comment: Inside `./userData/actions` there is `export`. I'm not sure about compiling targeting, how can I check that? the start script is `webpack-dev-server -d --config ./src/mock/webpack.config.babel.js --content-base ./src/mock --hot` also there is some babel config..